# Computing the gradient and Hessian of this function $f(b) = \log \int_{x\in\mathcal X} e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $$ f(b) = \log \int_{x\in\mathcal X} e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle} dx,$$
where $g: \mathcal X \to \mathbb R^n$.

Compute $\nabla f(b)$ and $\nabla^2 f(b)$.

This is my attempt, $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial b_i} = \frac{1}{\int_{x\in\mathcal X}e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle}}\int_{x\in \mathcal X}e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle}g_i(x)dx$$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial b_j}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial b_i}\right) = \frac{-1}{(\int_{x\in\mathcal X}e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle}dx)^2}\cdot \int_{x\in\mathcal X} e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle}g_j(x)dx \cdot \int_{x\in\mathcal X}e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle}g_i(x)dx + \frac{1}{\int_{x\in\mathcal X}e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle}}\cdot\int_{x\in\mathcal X}e^{\langle g(x), b\rangle}g_j(x) g_i(x)$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming that the scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is given by the standard dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.